# Obj-C, disable/enable screen rotation - does't work

Tags: objective-c

I trying to disable and enable screen rotation in some of my viewcontrollers but it is doesn't work, I get an error "use of undeclared identifier 'shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation' " I using IOS 8, what do I miss ?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your app to rotate for orientation and in every viewcontroller that you want the view to rotate return YES and No to the rest of the view controllers.

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
  return NO;
  }
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
  }

Once the app orientation is setup it maintains the orientation privilege and can't be changed in the middle of the app so you'll have to perform the extra task separately in all viewcontrollers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```